# 2-factors in a regular 2-edge connected graph

Tags: graph-theory

*Let G be a k-regular graph which is 2-edge connected. Show that G has a 2-factor.*

I know that in a 2 -edge connected graph there exists at least two edge disjoint paths between any two vertices , as a result of a general theorem by Menger on k-regular graphs.
I also know that we can show a k-regular, k even, 2-edge connected graph must have a perfect matching , but in order to prove this statement I need to find at least two edge disjoint perfect matchings and don’t know really where to start on that.
Also in the special case when k=3, we have  the Petersen’s theorem indicating that a cubic graph without a cut edge have a perfect matching.

Thanks In advance .

Comment: See  e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2813988)

Comment: @kabenyuk So the key of the question  is to discuss that $k$ is odd, i.e., any $2$-edge connected $k$-regular graph  has a $2$-factor.

Answer (score 1):

Bäbler proved a variation of the theorem stating that every $2k$-regular graph has a 2-factor, but specifically for certain graphs that include regular graphs of odd degree.

**Theorem 1**  (Bäbler, 1937). For every positive integer $k$, Every $2$-edge-connected ($2k + 1$)-regular graph (or multigraph) contains a $2$-factor.

[1] F. Bäbler, Über die Zerlegung regulärer Streckencomplexe ungerader Ordnung, Comment. Math. Helv. 10 (1937), 275–287. (Many authors mistakenly say the year of publication is 1938.)

However, this article is written in German, and since I do not understand German, I cannot see the methods used by the author.

In 1985, Bollobás, Saito and Wormald [2] classified the types of $k$-factors in an $r$-regular ($r ≥ 3$) graph with edge-connectivity $λ$ (which includes Theorem 1 for the case $r ≥ 3$, $r$ odd, and $λ = 2$).

Their proof is based on Tutte’s $k$-factor theorem.

[2] B. Bollobás, A. Saito, and N. C. Wormald, Regular factors of regular graphs, J. Graph theory 9 (1985), 97–103.

However, I am still interested in providing a more  direct proof for the specific question posed by the OP.  Perhaps a direct proof can be found in [1].